# Why is the error 'activities-heart-intraday' occurring in my for loop?

Tags: python, data-science

In this code, please explain why this error is occurring. I will 
share more code of it if anyone is interested.

```
fit_statsHR=auth2_client.intraday_time_series('activities/heart',base_date=date, detail_level='1sec')
time_list = []
val_list = []
ids = []
dates = []
for i in fit_statsHR['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']:
  val_list.append(i['value'])
  time_list.append(i['time'])
  ids.append(id)
  dates.append(date)

heartdf=pd.DataFrame({'heartRate':val_list,'time':time_list,'userId':ids,'date':dates})
```

which leads to:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)


<ipython-input-3-076c9750910b> in get_hps(auth2_client, id, date)
     51     ids = []
     52     dates = []
---> 53     for i in (fit_statsHR['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']):
     54         val_list.append(i['value'])
     55         time_list.append(i['time'])

KeyError: 'activities-heart-intraday'
```

Comment: your object `fit_statsHR` (which is presumably a dictionary) doesn't have an entry `'activities-heart-intraday'`, which is what you are trying to access

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?